# Extracting notes from a ppt file node js

Tags: node.js, powerpoint, extract, mern

So powerpoint allows us to add notes now I want to extract just the notes of the slide (the notes are transcripts in my case ). I've searched a lot but didn't found any way to do it. Is there any npm package or some API that might help me? I want to extract just the highlighted part of the image[I just want to extract these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRq5b.jpg)

If it's not possible I have a pdf where the slides are in a box and there is text at the bottom (I'll add pictures here's the link tho [link](https://smallpdf.com/blog/how-to-save-powerpoint-as-pdf-with-notes) the issue is if there is text on my slide pdf js finds that too but I need only the notes here.

Comment: What have you tried so far? 2 secs on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pptx2json

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. I found this api [link](https://docs.aspose.cloud/slides/download-a-slide-from-a-powerpoint-presentation/) now I just need the notes I couldn't find it most of the places it's just slide to image nothing more.
How to use pptx2json for this purpose
I am looking for something like pdf js for ppt so that I can extract the notes

Comment: If it's not possible I have a pdf where the slides are in a box and there is text at bottom (I'll add picture here's the link tho [link](https://smallpdf.com/blog/how-to-save-powerpoint-as-pdf-with-notes) is there a way to get only the text outside the box if yes please help

Comment: Neraly any "office document" is just xml with some other stuff. Read the docs about the ppt format and you can build a parser.

Comment: Hey thanks the XML was usefull I've found the notes there but I've a pptx file is there any way to convert it to xml in node js. If yes please share